# Get Inserted Row after .Net Dataset Row Added

Tags: c#, insert, dataset

I have a .Net dataset and am adding a row to a table. This works and the record is saved to the database. How do I get the updated version of my row after the insert. Or, alternatively, how do I know the ID of the item that was added (so that I can then use it in a subsequent child table insert.

```
MyDataSet.ProjectRow r = dsMyDataSet.Projects.AddProjectRow(txtTitle.Text);
m_daProjects.Update(dsMyDataSet.Projects);
// What is the ID of the new item here?
```

Comment: If the column is an identity column you can find the new ID's in the inserted rows.

Comment: thanks. which object maintains a list of inserted rows?

Answer (score 2):

If the column is an identity column you can find the new ID's in the inserted rows.

You: *"thanks. which object maintains a list of inserted rows?"*

You can use [`DataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.getchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a `DataTable` with all `DataRows` which are going to be added. You need to use it before `AcceptChanges` was called. If i remember correctly `TableAdapter.Update` calls `AcceptChanges` at the end. Then you need to use it before `m_daProjects.Update(dsMyDataSet.Projects)`:

```
DataTable addedRows = ds.modModel.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);
MyDataSet.ProjectRow r = dsMyDataSet.Projects.AddProjectRow(txtTitle.Text);
m_daProjects.Update(dsMyDataSet.Projects);
```

now `addedRows` contains all `DataRows` with the new identity value in each row

```
foreach(DataRow addedRow in addedRows.Rows)
    Console.WriteLine("New ID: {0}", addedRow.Field<int>("IdColumn"));
```

**Update**: However, in your case it's simpler. You have already the single row that you want to insert. So you dont need to call `DataTable.GetChanges` at all.

You can see the new identity value in the (typed `DataRow`) `ProjectRow r` after `Update`.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm still getting -1 as the identity field value in the typed row object after the Update. The database is Access and the dataset autoincrement is set to True (seed -1, increment value -1)

Comment: Look at following article and search for _"if you are using MS Access database"_: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdata/archive/2009/09/14/refresh-the-primary-key-identity-column-during-insert-operation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tim Schmelter. In the link he posted there's a reference to an article on Beth Massi's blog with a complete walkthrough of the solution. It worked for me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2009/05/14/using-tableadapters-to-insert-related-data-into-an-ms-access-database.aspx

The basic steps are:

1) Add RowUpdated event handler on the strongly typed table adapter. This event handler issues a new OleDBCommand to the database to retrieve @@Identity and then assigns the integer to the member column of the table.

```
public void _adapter_RowUpdated(dynamic sender, System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    HMUI.Classes.AccessIDHelper.SetPrimaryKey(this.Connection, e);
}

public static void SetPrimaryKey(OleDbConnection trans, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Status == System.Data.UpdateStatus.Continue && e.StatementType == System.Data.StatementType.Insert)
        {                
            if (pk != null)
            {
                OleDbCommand cmdGetIdentity = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", trans); 
                // Execute the post-update query to fetch new @@Identity
                e.Row.Table.Columns[pk(0)] = Convert.ToInt32(cmdGetIdentity.ExecuteScalar());
                e.Row.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

2) In the constructor of the form using the dataset and table adapter I attach the function in step 1 to the RowUpdated event on the table adapter's internal data adapter.

```
// Event to handle inserted records and retrieve the primary key ID
m_daDataSources.Adapter.RowUpdated += new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(m_daDataSources._adapter_RowUpdated);
```